# Is there a better way to create a new Python project from existing code in Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ptvs

I find it very cumbersome to create a new Python (I am using the PTVS extension) project in Visual Studio from existing code. What I am wanting to know is if there is a way to do this more efficiently.

Ideally, something that would live in the context menu in Windows Explorer, something like "New VS Project", that would open VS, create the project and import the source .py file. Is something like that possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of something like this. Personally I use the *Import from existing Code* dialog in Visual Studio. You could add this to the [issues list on CodePlex](https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic). Maybe it will be added in a future version.